# Using Python Higher Order Functions to Manipulate Lists

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I've made this list; each item is a string that contains commas (in some cases) and colon (always):

```
dinner = [
    'cake,peas,cheese : No',
    'duck,broccoli,onions : Maybe',
    'motor oil : Definitely Not',
    'pizza : Damn Right',
    'ice cream : Maybe',
    'bologna : No',
    'potatoes,bacon,carrots,water: Yes',
    'rats,hats : Definitely Not',
    'seltzer : Yes',
    'sleeping,whining,spitting : No Way',
    'marmalade : No'
]
```

I would like to create a new list from the one above as follows:

```
['cake : No',
 'peas : No',
 'cheese : No',
 'duck : Maybe',
 'broccoli : Maybe',
 'onions : Maybe',
 'motor oil : Definitely Not',
 'pizza : Damn Right',
 'ice cream : Maybe',
 'bologna : No',
 'potatoes : Yes',
 'bacon : Yes',
 'carrots : Yes',
 'water : Yes',
 'rats : Definitely Not',
 'hats : Definitely Not',
 'seltzer : Yes',
 'sleeping : No Way',
 'whining : No Way',
 'spitting : No Way',
 'marmalade : No']
```

But I'd like to know if/ how it's possible to do so in a line or two of efficient code employing primarily Python's higher order functions. I've been attempting it:

`reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, (map(lambda x: x.split(':')[0].strip().split(','), dinner)))`

...produces this:

```
['cake',
 'peas',
 'cheese',
 'duck',
 'broccoli',
 'onions',
 'motor oil',
 'pizza',
 'ice cream',
 'bologna',
 'potatoes',
 'bacon',
 'carrots',
 'water',
 'rats',
 'hats',
 'seltzer',
 'sleeping',
 'whining',
 'spitting',
 'marmalade']
```

...but I'm struggling with appending the piece of each string after the colon back onto each item.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the code length? This would be much less maintainable in the long term.

Comment: @jpmc26 I understand where you're coming from and agree. This for me is more an exploratory exercise in understanding the capabilities of Python's hofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really need it as a list of strings vs. a dictionary, which looks like a better data structure.

By simplify using comprehensions you can do this:

```
>>> [[x+':'+y for x in i.split(',')]
...  for i, y in map(lambda l: map(str.strip, l.split(':')), dinner)]
[['cake:No', 'peas:No', 'cheese:No'],
 ['duck:Maybe', 'broccoli:Maybe', 'onions:Maybe'],
 ['motor oil:Definitely Not'],
 ...
 ['marmalade:No']]
```

Now just `add` up the lists:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> reduce(add, ([x+':'+y for x in i.split(',')]
...              for i, y in map(lambda l: map(str.strip, l.split(':')), dinner)), [])
['cake:No',
 'peas:No',
 'cheese:No',
 'duck:Maybe',
 ...
 'marmalade:No']
```

Or just flatten the list:

```
>>> [a for i, y in map(lambda l: map(str.strip, l.split(':')), dinner) 
...  for a in (x+':'+y for x in i.split(','))]
['cake:No',
 'peas:No',
 'cheese:No',
 'duck:Maybe',
 ...
 'marmalade:No']
```

Comment: `flatten` is built-in as `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Comment: @AChampion thank you. Several people have posted great code that works well, but your response was more aligned with my goal.

Answer (score 8):

I would create a dict using, `zip`, `map` and [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
from itertools import repeat


data = ({k.strip(): v.strip() for _k, _v in map(lambda x: x.split(":"), dinner)
     for k, v in zip(_k.split(","), repeat(_v))})

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(data)
```

Output:

```
{'bacon': 'Yes',
 'bologna': 'No',
 'broccoli': 'Maybe',
 'cake': 'No',
 'carrots': 'Yes',
 'cheese': 'No',
 'duck': 'Maybe',
 'hats': 'Definitely Not',
 'ice cream': 'Maybe',
 'marmalade': 'No',
 'motor oil': 'Definitely Not',
 'onions': 'Maybe',
 'peas': 'No',
 'pizza': 'Damn Right',
 'potatoes': 'Yes',
 'rats': 'Definitely Not',
 'seltzer': 'Yes',
 'sleeping': 'No Way',
 'spitting': 'No Way',
 'water': 'Yes',
 'whining': 'No Way'}
```

Or using the dict constructor:

```
from itertools import repeat

data = dict(map(str.strip, t) for _k, _v in map(lambda x: x.split(":"), dinner)
            for t in zip(_k.split(","), repeat(_v)))

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(data)
```

If you really want a list of strings, we can do something similar using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and joining the substrings:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

data = chain.from_iterable(map(":".join, zip(_k.split(","), repeat(_v))) 
                           for _k, _v in map(lambda x: x.split(":"), dinner))


from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(list(data))
```

Output:

```
['cake: No',
 'peas: No',
 'cheese : No',
 'duck: Maybe',
 'broccoli: Maybe',
 'onions : Maybe',
 'motor oil : Definitely Not',
 'pizza : Damn Right',
 'ice cream : Maybe',
 'bologna : No',
 'potatoes: Yes',
 'bacon: Yes',
 'carrots: Yes',
 'water: Yes',
 'rats: Definitely Not',
 'hats : Definitely Not',
 'seltzer : Yes',
 'sleeping: No Way',
 'whining: No Way',
 'spitting : No Way',
 'marmalade : No']
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
def processList (aList):
    finalList = []
    for aListEntry in aList:
        aListEntry_entries = aListEntry.split(':')
        aListEntry_list = aListEntry_entries[0].split(',')
        for aListEntry_list_entry in aListEntry_list:
            finalList.append(aListEntry_list_entry.strip() + ' : ' + aListEntry_entries[1].strip())
    return finalList
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are preferred in Python (check eg [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)), due to better legibility (at least for some;).

The code demonstrates two types of list comprehension nesting, the first is basically chaining the operations, the other produces one list from two nested loops.

If you make your data more consistent by adding one space after the `carrots, water`, you can get rid of two `.strip()` calls;)

```
dinner = [
    'cake,peas,cheese : No',
    'duck,broccoli,onions : Maybe',
    'motor oil : Definitely Not',
    'pizza : Damn Right',
    'ice cream : Maybe',
    'bologna : No',
    'potatoes,bacon,carrots,water : Yes',
    'rats,hats : Definitely Not',
    'seltzer : Yes',
    'sleeping,whining,spitting : No Way',
    'marmalade : No'
]

prefs = [(pref, items.split(',')) for items, pref in [it.split(" : ") for it in dinner]]
[" : ".join([item, pref]) for pref, items in prefs for item in items]
```